# Selenium error when deleting cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Has anyone encountered this issue when Selenium tries to delete cookies?

After months of working fine and not changing anything, we're suddenly hitting this error when running tests:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"(FE3E5C7422F34F92AF238C0A8EBA89BF)","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
      (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteCookieJar.DeleteAllCookies()
       at FluentAutomation.CommandProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at FluentAutomation.CommandProvider.get_webDriver()
       at FluentAutomation.CommandProvider.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindMultiple>b__a()
       at FluentAutomation.ElementProxy.get_Elements()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"(FE3E5C7422F34F92AF238C0A8EBA89BF)","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
      (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **compatibility** between the *Version* of the *Binaries* you are using.

- You are using **chromedriver=2.9**
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.9*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **Supports Chrome v31-34**

- You are using *Chrome Browser* version **64.0**

So there is a clear **mismatch** between the *Version* of the *Binaries*.

### Solution

- Upgrade your *ChromeDriver* to recent **ChromeDriver=2.35** level.
- As per the Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) upgrade your *Chrome Browser* to **Chrome v62-64** levels.
- If your base *Chrome Browser* version is too old uninstall *Chrome Browser* through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent released GA version of *Chrome Browser*
- Execute your *Tests*