# WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': while initializing Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get started using selenium and have downloaded a chrome driver and put into my classpath. I'm just trying to get the title right now to see if I can get it to work. Code currently looks like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Flows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/mn/Desktop/project/turv/src/main/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://google.dk/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I expected my output to be something along the lines of "Google", but I get this error instead:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55299', transport: 'socket'
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241036) on port 2571
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
May 07, 2018 12:12:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55299', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"11895A1B77AC560388AA2919259E1422","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241036,platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'cetreas-MBP', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9e:2c67:1d27:4e0b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {userDataDir: /var/folders/s7/lv2wt4t15cn...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, version: 66.0.3359.139, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: ca1f4ba131e73c3d01058bec2b976d22
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:273)
    at com.cetrea.flows.Flows.main(Flows.java:15)
```

I cant really figure out what the error is trying to tell me. Is it because I'm asking for the title before it has fully loaded the site maybe? Do I need to add some kind of `waitforit` command before the `getTitle()` ?

Comment: Doesn't look like anything within your code. You may need to update both chrome and chromedriver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium error when deleting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805882/selenium-error-when-deleting-cookies)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"11895A1B77AC560388AA2919259E1422","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.8* which is **pretty ancient**.
- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.8*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v66.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.